# Set box zoom (or pan or wheel zoom) as default in using Holoviews or Hvplot

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot, holoviz

My hvplot has default pan and wheel zoom as way of zooming and moving the graph. 
But I want box zoom to be the default in my graph.
How do I do this in hvplot or holoviews?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
import hvplot
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(size=[50, 2]), columns=['a', 'b'])
df_plot = df.hvplot.scatter(x='a', y='b')
```

[image: hvplot pan is default active tool]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default setting can be changed to the one you need by adding **.opts(active_tools=['box_zoom'])** if you need box zoom.

So add the following to your code:

```
df_plot.opts(active_tools=['box_zoom'])
```

In the same way you can choose to set **'pan'** or **'wheel_zoom'** as the active tools.

For holoviews the answer would be very similar, for example:

```
hv.Scatter(df).opts(active_tools=['box_zoom'])
```

[image: box_zoom is now set as active tool]